# extending width of floated div

Tags: html, css

Given two floated divs whose width takes 50% of their container when aligned side by side, is it possible to have their width extend all the way to 100% when the screen is shrunk to the point where the second div has to be pushed one row down?

Take the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGMgJL) for example, and shrink the window horizontally until the green div and its container move below the red one. Is it possible to have the width of `#wrap1` and `#wrap2` extend all the way to the right of `#container`, so that `#one` and `#two` are centered with respect to `#container`? i.e. so it would look like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJOMaE).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Not automatically using floats...but `flexbox` absolutely.

Comment: Try using media queries. When the browser shrinks to a certain px width then it'll use what ever css you tell it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Use media-queries for that

Comment: right thanks. was hoping I was missing a simple solution using clear and whatnot but media queries/flexbox should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flexbox` solution..no media query required as such.

```css
#container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[class^="wrap"] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: none;
}
.wrap1 {
  background: rgba(100, 10, 10, .2);
}
.wrap2 {
  background: rgba(10, 100, 10, .2);
 height: 100px;
}
#one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 0, .1);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#two {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 0, .1);
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="wrap1">
    <div id="one">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div id="two">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pJOMKN?editors=110)

Comment: I'll go with that one as it doesn't need media queries. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not working with dynamic widths, you can add a media query to change the container behaviour on the wrap position.

Otherwise you need to refer to flexbox bevhaviour – [this guide by Dimitar Stojanov](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) has some examples on wrapping.

[Edit:] fixed link.

Answer (score 1):

You should use flexbox. [Here is your Pen edited](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpxOxN)

CSS:

```
#container{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #container{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.wrap1{
  background: rgba(100,10,10,.2);
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrap2{
  background: rgba(10,100,10,.2);
  height: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You'll want to create a fluid container, and then create two inner div's. The inner divs will have class col-md-6 which will be 50% for large screens and col-xs-12 for xtra small screens. This will auto resize with the browser.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">Div 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">Div 2</div>
</div>
```